# The most basic MySQL UDF code for Windows

Tags: mysql, c, user-defined-functions

I am trying to  create the most basic user defined function for MySQL.

```
#include <mysql.h>

extern "C" {
    my_bool foo_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);
    char *foo(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error);
}

my_bool foo_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    return 0;
}

char *foo(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,  char *is_null, char *error) {
    return "";
}
```

It compiled fine, but when I try to create function from it

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo RETURNS STRING SONAME "mysql_plugin2.dll"
```

It said  `SQL Error (1127): Can't find symbol 'foo' in library`

Answer (score 1):

1. The foo() function must change as `char *foo(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *error)`
2. Add foo_deinit() function. The Mysql UDF require 3 functions and name like `udf_name_init`, `udf_name` and `udf_name_deinit`.
3. Compile and put the dll file under the  `<mysql_installation_folder>/lib/plugin/`.

the following code haven't be tested, but it should work.

```
#include <mysql.h>

my_bool
foo_init(UDF_INIT *initid,
         UDF_ARGS *args,
         char     *message)
{
    return 0;
}

char *
foo(UDF_INIT      *initid,
    UDF_ARGS      *args,
    char          *result,
    unsigned long *length,
    char          *is_null,
    char          *error)
{
     // specified the return string length
     // see item_func.cc line #3440 and #3454 
     // https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/9cc7789e9084e7d59a43f9560870e496843535f9/sql/item_func.cc#L3440
     *length = 0;
     return "";
}

void
foo_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid)
{
    // nothing...
}
```